# How to calculate median in Crate

Tags: median, crate

I am using Crate 0.54.7 and have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int PRIMARY KEY, val int);
```

Now I want to get the median of val. The query I used in Postgresql so far did not work:

```
SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) FROM test;
```

Is there any way I can calculate the median in Crate?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Crate (as of 0.54.X).

But there are two feature requests on Github

- [1 Percentile Aggregation?](https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/3379)
- [2 Quantiles Aggregation](https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/1791)